# django categories views(error page not found)

Tags: python, django, django-views, pycharm, django-urls

my task is to create on main page of my web site two list one list for my post
and second list categories titles which belong my post.
i create that and work fine,and i create post details connect and again work fine.
but i cant to work category details if i want to see list from my post which belong specific category i cant show me error page not found.

my code

my model

```
class Category(models.Model):
 categorytitle =models.CharField(max_length=1,choices=CAT_CHOICES,unique=True)
 slug= models.SlugField()


class Posts(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    slug= models.SlugField()
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

my view category

```
def view_category(request, slug):
category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=slug)
return render_to_response('blog/view_category.html', {
    'category': category,
    'posts': Posts.objects.filter(category=category)
})
```

my urls category

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', views.view_category, name='view_category'),
```

main template tags

```
{% for category in categories %}
<li><a href="{{ category.slug }}">{{ category.categorytitle }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

error message

Page not found (404)
Request Method:
GET 
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/category1/ 
Raised by:
blog.views.view_post 
No Posts matches the given query.

my view post

```
def view_post(request, slug):
    return render_to_response('blog/movies_details.html', {
        'post': get_object_or_404(Movies,slug=slug)
    })
```

my urls view

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', views.view_post, name='view_post'),
```

[if i use browser db for sqlite view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDpbu.jpg)

Comment: main page or category template ?

Comment: i thing not template error because show me page not found

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex in urls.py to:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.view_category, name='view_category'),
```

`\w` = alphanumeric signs + underscore

`-` = hyphen

(These characters are now allowed in the slug)

And change the Post filter to:

```
Posts.objects.filter(category_id=category.id)
```

#### NOTE:

1. Posts filtering have to placed before rendering, not in it (do it in the same way like "category")
2. How do you create slugs in the Category model? In admin? Manually or automatically via prepopulated_fields? Because I don'ŧ like in the `categorytitle` field the `max_length=1`

Comment: can you send me an example for your NOTE 1. ?i change that my max_length is 10 ' prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('categorytitle',)}'

Comment: Normally, do it in the same way like the category variable in the function (views). Do NOT Post.objects.filter in the RETURN, but do it before. Got it?

Comment: i use your code i change my code but not work again same error i thing so the problem is my query on the view because show me error "No Posts matches the given query".

Comment: Check my edited post, I've modified the Post filter.

Comment: i use that your update code but no change same error "No Posts matches the given query"

Comment: Are you sure that you are requesting the right URL and the slug in the URL exists in the database? I don't think so, because you had wrong model defined and maybe you still forget update the data in the DB.

Comment: + show me the CAT_CHOICES, I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: yeah i am sure for that look my images on my ask i update now for you....just not upload here i thing not necesery

Answer (score 0):

If your error message shows: "Raised by: blog.views.view_post" Than obviously django is hitting view_post function in your views and not view_category.
Due to wrong function call view_post can't find the post with slug:"category1" so gives a 404 error ( obviously!! ).
So i will suggest to check out if there is a url mismatch that is causing this first.

Comment: i have view post and work fine i update my answer with that view and url

Comment: you are correct if i delete 'url(r'^(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', views.view_post, name='view_post')' work but i need views_post how to have together without error ?thnx

Comment: i find it thnx for the help

Comment: As i guessed your view_post and view_category urls are identical. So the one you put at top is used by django. Use something like : url(r'^post/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', views.view_post, name='view_post'), and url(r'^category/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', views.view_category, name='view_category'). Happy to help. If your problem is solved accept as answer thx.

Answer (score 0):

So I had a similar problem, did all I could by reading various solutions and none was helpful. My solution was real funny(ironic) since I spent an hour to find out what was wrong.

In the urls.py, the order of the url s is pretty important.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('shop.urls')),
    url(r'^shpcart/', include('shpcart.urls')), 
]
```

The above pattern kept saying 404 shpcart/ not found, but shpcart was already there.

Just as I was about to find myself trying to persuade the pc, I moved the shpcart url 1 line above, everything started to sound. If anyone is stuck like I was, hope this helps

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^shpcart/', include('shpcart.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('shop.urls')),
]
```